# Excel VBA ActiveX Combobox Change Event Fires on every keystroke

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have an ActiveX combobox placed directly on a worksheet that I need the user to be able to either pick from the dropdown list or if the user knows the correct text to type it directly in the combobox.

I have a lot of code behind the change event of this combobox.  The issue is that when a user begins typing text into the combobox the change event fires on every keystroke.  I need the change event to fire after the enter key is pressed only.

How do I get the change event of the combobox to fire only after the enter key is pressed when typing directly into the combobox?

Comment: You don't.  Sounds like you're looking for the `AfterUpdate` event.

Comment: I dont' see that the AfterUpdate event is avaialble for the ActiveX combobox I have on my sheet.

I also tried the Click event but that doesn't fire when user types text into the combobox and presses enter.

LostFocus event requires the user to click outside the combobox and does nothing when the user presses the enter key.

Is there an ActiveX combobox event that will fire when a user presses enter on the combobox. What over events should I try?

Comment: Missed the "directly on a worksheet" part. You could try the `LostFocus` event instead and\or handle the Enter key exiting the cell in the `KeyDown` event.

Comment: Not a simple fix (AFAIK there is no "Enter Key Press" event).  The `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` events fire when Enter is pressed.

Comment: Need to use `_KeyDown` event to capture the Enter Key (KeyCode 13). You may want to check if there is an actual matched item by `.ListIndex <> -1`